# Calling customized R function in pandas with dependencies

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

I'm trying to manipulate a pandas dataframe with a customized R function. The problem that I face is that the built-in '*required*' function is not recognized and therefore the underlying dependencies are not recognized.

Python script:

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import STAP
import pandas as pd

r_script_full_name =  'C:\\Users\\Example.R'

matrix = [(222, 34, 23),
         (333, 31, 11),
         (444, 16, 21),
         (555, 32, 22),
         (666, 33, 27),
         (777, 35, 11)
         ]
pandas2ri.activate()
df = pandas2ri.py2ri(pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns = list('abc')))

with open(r_script_full_name, 'r') as f:
    my_script = STAP(f.read(), "my_script")

output = my_script.apply_function(df)
```

R function:

```
apply_function <- function(df){
  
  require(data.table)
  df <- setDT(df)
  df[, test := 1]
  return(df)
  
}
```

I'm getting the following error: setDT not recognized. I have a few more underlying dependencies that I try to load. Is there any way I can make this work?

Comment: can you not write the function in Python? Or do everything in Python? or even in R?

Comment: Yes of course! I was playing around with the rpy2 package and was curious to see if this was possible.